# How do I make my text appear on click button in react native?

Tags: react-native

```js
<TextInput style={{ width: 300, height: 150, borderStyle: "solid", borderWidth: 2, fontSize: 30 }} placeholder="New Post">

</TextInput>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handlePress} style={{ marginLeft: 250, width: 80, height: 40 }}>
        <Text>Enter</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

handlePress = () => {

}
```

How do I construct my handlePress function so that my text on textinput appear on the box below?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TouchableOpacity, Text, TextInput } from "react-native";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    TextInputValueHolder: "",
    button: ""
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <TextInput
          style={{
            height: 150,
            borderStyle: "solid",
            borderWidth: 2,
            fontSize: 30
          }}
          placeholder="New Post"
          onChangeText={TextInputValueHolder =>
            this.setState({ TextInputValueHolder })
          }
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.handlePress}
          style={{ background: "red", marginLeft: 0, width: 80, height: 40 }}
        >
          <Text>{this.state.button}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </>
    );
  }
  handlePress = () => {
    const value = this.state.TextInputValueHolder;
    console.log("value", value);

    this.setState({ button: value });
  };
}

export default App;
```

[image: Reference Screenshots]

Comment: Yeap theres a red line under TextInputValueHolder

Comment: still red underline on TextInputValueHolder and an error

Comment: Inside a handlePress function, there is a red line under const, and button. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213139/discussion-between-rajan-and-sean-lee).

Comment: can you send me a message? i dont know how to use a chat